# Does any assigned variable equal(==) to an "raw_input()" in Python2?

Tags: python-2.7, raw-input

The "raw_input" is generally used for taking a respond of prompt to a string, and then it can be also assigned(=) by a variable.

But I found something strange(for me) and can't well understand. In a mistake incident case(see example below), I put a equal(==) for assigning variable in a function. Then I run it in interpreter and didn't have any error. I through my script was well done but it could not work as my expert.

My questions:
I would like to know this usage of "raw_input" in Python is correct? 
If yes, how we use it?
If not, why don't interpreter give us a error warning?

Thank you so much.

Example:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2012, 00:00:54) 
[GCC 4.7.0 20120414 (prerelease)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> v = "Variable"
>>> def test():
...     v == raw_input(">")
...     print v
... 
>>> test()
>Hello!
Variable
>>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
v == raw_input(">")
```

is simply a comparison.  You get `True` or `False` as a result and then throw it away, because you don't give it a name.  You could write

```
comparison = v == raw_input(">")
print comparison
```

to see the value.